# Store two types of value in single Django model field

Tags: python, sql, django, sqlite, django-models

I am learning django by creating a polling application. For starters I have three models User, Question and Choices.

```
class User(....):
    ....
    Questions_voted = models.ManyToManyField(Question)
    ....
```

this means that a user to vote for as many questions as he wants. Next is The Question Model which is simple and just store question text and number of people voted for it.

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    vote_count = models.IntegerField(...)
```

next is Choices which have a choice_text and refers to the question it belongs to.

```
class Choice(models.Models):
    choice_text = models.CharField(models.Model)
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question,...)
```

Now I want to store information about what choice a user selected for a question. It is very clear when you think of it but I am stuck because of lack of knowledge of types of fields in django models.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you to change model schema. Here is suggested model:

[image: Suggested ER model]

I added `UserVote` model that holds information about `Question` and `Choice` selected by `User`.

```
from django.conf import settings

class UserVote(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey('Question')
    choice = models.ForeignKey('Choice')
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
```

EDIT: How to read suggested schema: `User` can have many `UserVote`s (there is `Many-To-One` relation – in Django you simply add `ForeignKey` to `UserVote`). Each `UserVote` must have one-and-only one `Question` and `Choice`. The rest is your old schema. Btw I used Crow's foot notation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93relationship_model#Crow.27s_foot_notation).

Comment: Yes, there is `Many-To-One` relation. See edit of my answer.